# Is stealth bomber bomb damage uniform?

Tags: eve-online

Is the damage on the outer area of the explosion of a bomb deployed by a stealth bomber smaller or equivalent to damage in the center of the explosion of a bomb?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated on the eve [wiki](https://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Bombs_%28Ammunition%29) the only factor that affects how much damage a bomb does to a ship is the ratio of the ship's signature radius to the bomb's explosion radius. The distance of the ship from the explosion's epicenter has no effect on the amount of damage dealt.

Answer (score 3):

According to information I lurked out on Eve Forums, the only thing that affects the damage a bomb inflicts to a target is it's Singature Radius vs Bomb explosion velocity (or something like that).

Other than that, bombs do **not** deal less damage closer to their max explosion range.